# To prove $f(g(x))$ is continuous at $c$

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, continuity, relations

$f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions such that $g$ is continuous at $c$ and $f$ is continuous at $g(c)$. then to prove $f(g(x))$ is continuous at $c$.

I have no clue how to start. Would be helpful if please share your ideas.

Comment: Write down the definition of continuity for $f(g(x))$ and work backward to satisfy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write down the definition of $g$ being continuous at $c$, the definition of $f$ being continuous at $g(c)$, and the definition of $f \circ g$ being continuous at $c$. Combine the first two appropriately to obtain the continuity of $f \circ g$.